# How can I remove the parent div of a looped element?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to remove the parent div of a text, that is looped for every flash.
I tried getting the Element by Id but it only deletes the first flashed text.
This is the code:

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <div class="todolistitems">
            <b id="todoitem">{{ message }}</b>
            <button onClick="testremove()" id="deletetodo"><i class="material-icons">done</i></button>
            
            <br>
        </div>
        <script>
            var msg = document.getElementById("todoitem")
            

              
            function testremove() {
                msg.parentNode.remove(); 
                               
            }
        </script>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should only have one element per ID. Try using another identifier, like a data attribute or classes.

Comment: i tried classes but i didn't know how to get the count in the [ ] for each text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to handle this.

First, don't use the same ID more than once. But, there's no need to use them at all here. We can listen to `document` for a click event and then test to see if it's a delete button. If so, remove the element associated with that button. How to find that element? Easiest to group them together inside a `div` container and then use the ever-handy `.closest(parentSelector)` method. When we listen for the delete click, we need to consider that depending on where in that button the user clicks, the `target` of the `event` will either be the button or the icon within

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (['material-icons', 'btn-delete'].some(c => e.target.classList.contains(c))) {
      let targ = e.target.closest('.todo-item')
      console.log(targ)
      targ.parentNode.removeChild(targ)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="todolistitems">
  <div class='todo-item'>
    <b class='msg'>todo1</b>
    <button class='btn-delete'><i class="material-icons">done</i></button>
  </div>
  <div class='todo-item'>
    <b class='msg'>todo2</b>
    <button class='btn-delete'><i class="material-icons">done</i></button>
  </div>
  <div class='todo-item'>
    <b class='msg'>todo3</b>
    <button class='btn-delete'><i class="material-icons">done</i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```